# Have a result from several conditions on Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets

I have set up a Sheets file to have the list of the personnel of a company. Each line corresponds to a person and each column to a data of this same person. There is the date of entry in the company, the name of the person, his first name, if he followed the mandatory training and if he was present the first day of work.

I am trying to set up indicators and one of them is causing a problem. I would like to have a column where a certain result appears based on the data entered in the "here in formation?" and "here 1st day?" columns. Unfortunately, I can't combine the logical AND operator in my IFS to get the desired result.

You can see via [this link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1jlKiLvjPped4UeO_iertjUVgQzCDshRhfwnlHElP52c/edit?usp=sharing) the expected results in column F according to the data present in the above mentioned columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest having an additional `IFS` layer. The idea would be to first check the `D` value, and for each of those values add an `IFS` that will check the `E` value.

#### Formula:

```
=IF(B2<>"";
    IFS(D2="Yes";IFS(E2="";"Data not completed";E2="Yes";"Yes";E2="No";"No");
        D2="No";IFS(E2="";"No";E2="No";"No");
        D2="Formation < 1 year";IFS(E2="Yes";"Yes";E2="No";"No";E2="";"Data not completed");
        D2="other formation";IFS(E2="Yes";"Yes";E2="No";"No";E2="";"Data not completed");
        D2="No need";IFS(E2="No";"No";E2="";"No"));"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help, it's perfect for what i want !!

Answer (score 0):

supreme fx:

```
=INDEX(IF(B2:B="";;IF(REGEXMATCH(D2:D&E2:E; 
 "^No(?: need)?(?:No)?$"); "No"; 
 IF(E2:E=""; "Data not completed"; E2:E))))
```

[image]